# Split non-square matrix into square sub-matrices

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix

Given any non-square matrix. I'm looking for an algorithm to split it into `N` square sub-matrices. It is not need it that all the element of the original matrix are in the new sub-matrices (actually is not always possible), but those should be as less as possible. Also I just need one solution, not all possible combinations.

For example if `N=2` and the matrix is 2x4, one division could be:

```
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2
```

If it would be 2x5 then:

```
1 1 2 2 -
1 1 2 2 -
```

Now the last column is not assigned to any sub-matrix.

What is fixed is the size of the original array and the fact that the `N` sub-matrices have to be square. So I have to find the rank of the indices of the new arrays. In this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910097/split-square-into-small-squares), they ask for a similar problem but, the original matrix is square, and they look up for all the combinations, where in this case, I just need one solution and the original matrix does not have to be square.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a Top Down Recursive approach.

Given a matrix `(x,y,h,w)||(Top Left x-coord, Top Left y-coord, Height, Width)`, I did the following:-

Suppose matrix =

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I selected squares of all possible sizes from the top left corner:-

Possibility 1:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Possibility 2:

```
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Possibility 3:

```
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
```

Then I divided the remaining space into 2 rectangles and recursed for the same.

For Example Possibility #2 can be broken in two ways, `x` and `y` denote the two new working halves:

Way 1:

```
1 1 y y y
1 1 y y y
x x y y y
```

Way 2:

```
1 1 y y y
1 1 y y y
x x x x x
```

Here is an implementation in Python:

```
import sys,copy
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**4)


def display_final_matrix(arr_matrix):
    temp =[['-' for i in range(init_matrix[3])] for j in range(init_matrix[2])]
    ctr=ord('a')
    for matrix in arr_matrix:
        for i in range(matrix[1],matrix[1]+matrix[2]):
            for j in range(matrix[0],matrix[0]+matrix[3]):
                temp[i][j]=chr(ctr)
        ctr+=1
    for i in temp:
        print(i)

def find_min_leftover(matrix,n):
    x = matrix[0]
    y = matrix[1]
    h = matrix[2]
    w = matrix[3]
    if  n==0:
        return h*w, []

    min_left=1<<64
    result_arr=[]
    for i in range(1,min(h,w)+1):
        current_selection = [x,y,i,i]

        # Possibility 1
        mtr1 = [x+i,y+0,h,w-i]
        mtr2 = [x+0,y+i,h-i,i]
        for j in range(n):
            left_mtr1 , mtr1_subselection = find_min_leftover(mtr1,j)
            left_mtr2 , mtr2_subselection = find_min_leftover(mtr2,n-1-j)
            if left_mtr1 + left_mtr2 < min_left:
                min_left = left_mtr1+left_mtr2
                result_arr =[current_selection]+mtr1_subselection+mtr2_subselection

        # Possibility 2

        mtr1 = [x+i,y+0,i,w-i]
        mtr2 = [x+0,y+i,h-i,w]
        for j in range(n):
            left_mtr1 , mtr1_subselection = find_min_leftover(mtr1,j)
            left_mtr2 , mtr2_subselection = find_min_leftover(mtr2,n-1-j)
            if left_mtr1 + left_mtr2 < min_left:
                min_left = left_mtr1+left_mtr2
                result_arr =[current_selection]+mtr1_subselection+mtr2_subselection

    return min_left,result_arr




# Top Left x-coord, Top Left y-coord, Height, Width
init_matrix = [0,0,6,6]

min_left,final_matrix = find_min_leftover(init_matrix,5)


print(min_left)
print(final_matrix)
display_final_matrix(final_matrix)
```

Output for filling a `6x6` matrix with 5 squares:

```
4
[[0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 2], [2, 2, 4, 4], [0, 2, 2, 2], [0, 4, 2, 2]]
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', '-', '-']
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', '-', '-']
['d', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
['d', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
['e', 'e', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
['e', 'e', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Memoization is possible since `0<=x,y,h,w<=Max Size`.

A 4D DP table will work faster and can store all the results at once but I implemented the recursive approach since it's more intuitive and will be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't say it (now I have edited it) but I need all sub-matrices being of the same size. Sorry I thought it was implicit but clearly not. My fault.

Comment: I guess @orlp's answer is what you should go for in that case.

Comment: @Xbel No, my answer doesn't work for all sub-matrices being the same size. That is indeed a very critical requirement. I would suggest asking a new question with that requirement added.

Comment: @Xbel You can calculate if `N` squares of a given size can be placed in the given rectangle in `O(1)`. From there you can binary search the answer as all squares of size up to the answer will fit in and no larger one will. @orlp this should work right?

Comment: Ok. Thanks to everyone. I guess the most fair decision is to open a new question and accept rhe answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to show that a greedy algorithm will always end up covering as much as it can.

So scan your matrix for the first element not yet covered (e.g. left-to-right top-to-bottom), and create a new 1 × 1 square submatrix here. Keep expanding this towards the bottomright to a 2 × 2, 3 × 3, etc submatrix as long as it fits inside the original matrix. When stuck, start from the beginning until you have created N submatrices.